# Save file to internal storage in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to make a simple Android application which will make user write text and when he presses on save button I'll get the text from text area and create folder then save file into folder in the storage.
I did that but in external storage and here's my code

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/newfolder";
                File f = new File(path);
                f.mkdir();
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(path + "/" + txt_name.getText() + ".txt");
                pw.write(main_txt.getText().toString());
                pw.close();
```

This code runs well but it runs only on devices which have an external memory card, so I want to do the same but save file on internal storage for device to make this code run on any device, how can I save file into internal storage?

Comment: What result were you expecting? What debugging have you done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Your code saves to external memory which is build into the phone.

Your code has nothing to do with a removable micro SD card.

Comment: but when I try to save text on my phone I get this message
/storage/emulated/0/newfolder\test.txt (No such file or directory)
my phone without memory card, so why I get this message ?

Comment: There can be several reasons. For instance you need write permission. What did you do to obtain permission? Further on Android Q you have to do still more.

Comment: Your code is not ok as you first have to create 'newfolder' and hence the message should have been first that the folder could not be created.

Comment: I wrote this permission on Android
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

Comment: That is not enough. Google for runtime permission.

Comment: but it create folder well when I run code on virtual device